# Angular Error with NgRX - No EntityDefinition for entity type [x]

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I am taking an app from Angular 8 to 10 and it seems as if I messed something up. I have a few resolvers and one is giving me an error. I can't figure what is different about the entity or the data service that is causing the problem. I am also not sure what this error message claims is missing and where it should be.

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: No EntityDefinition for entity type "makVersion".
```

Here is the offending feature module.

```
// Standard Angular Items
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';


// Angular Material Items
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
import { MatRippleModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { MatCarouselModule } from '@ngmodule/material-carousel';




// Mak components
import { NavbarModule } from '../Shared/navbar/navbar.module';
import { ProjectsComponent } from './projects.component';



// Services
import { ProjectsService } from '../services/projects.service';


// NgRx Items
import { EntityDataService, EntityDefinitionService, EntityMetadataMap } from '@ngrx/data';



// Entity Service
import { makDesignEntityService } from '../services/entity/makDesign-entity.service';
import { makDesignDataService } from '../services/entity/makDesign-data.service';
import { signoffReqEntityService } from '../services/entity/signoffReq-entity.service';
import { signoffReqDataService } from '../services/entity/signoffReq-data.service';
import { makProjectEntityService } from '../services/entity/makProject-entity.service';
import { makProjectDataService } from '../services/entity/makProject-data.service';
import { makVersionEntityService } from '../services/entity/makVersion-entity.service';
import { makVersionDataService } from '../services/entity/makVersion-data.service';
import { designImagesReducer } from '../store/reducers';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';



// The resolvers
import { MakDesignsResolver } from '../resolvers/makDesigns.resolver';
import { SignoffReqsResolver } from '../resolvers/signoffReqs.resolver';
import { MakProjectsResolver } from '../resolvers/makProjects.resolver';
import { MakVersionsResolver } from '../resolvers/makVersions.resolver';








// NgRX related metadata for NgData
const entityMetadata: EntityMetadataMap = {
    makDesign: {
        entityDispatcherOptions: {
            optimisticUpdate: true
        }
    },
    signoffReq: {
        entityDispatcherOptions: {
            optimisticUpdate: true
        }
    },
    makProject: {
        entityDispatcherOptions: {
            optimisticUpdate: true
        }
    },
    makVersion: {
        entityDispatcherOptions: {
            optimisticUpdate: true
        }
    },
};



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ProjectsComponent,
  ],
  imports    : [
    StoreModule.forFeature('designs', designImagesReducer),


    NavbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatCarouselModule,

  ],
  providers   : [
    ProjectsService,
    makDesignEntityService,
    makDesignDataService,
    signoffReqEntityService,
    signoffReqDataService,
    makProjectEntityService,
    makProjectDataService,
    makVersionEntityService,
    makVersionDataService,
    MakDesignsResolver,
    MakProjectsResolver,
    MakVersionsResolver,
    SignoffReqsResolver,
  ]
})
export class ProjectsModule
{

  constructor(
    private eds: EntityDefinitionService,
    private entityDataService: EntityDataService,
    private makDesignDataService: makDesignDataService,
    private signoffReqDataService: signoffReqDataService,
    private makProjectDataService: makProjectDataService,
    private makVersionDataService: makVersionDataService
    ){
      eds.registerMetadataMap(entityMetadata);
      entityDataService.registerService('makDesign', makDesignDataService);
      entityDataService.registerService('signoffReq', signoffReqDataService);
      entityDataService.registerService('makProject', makProjectDataService);
      entityDataService.registerService('makVersion', makVersionDataService);
    }

}
```

The store is the app.module

```
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {
        metaReducers,
        runtimeChecks : {
            strictStateImmutability: true,
            strictActionImmutability: true,
            strictActionSerializability: true,
            strictStateSerializability:true
        }
    }),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({maxAge: 25, logOnly: environment.production}),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
    EntityDataModule.forRoot({}),
    StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot({
        stateKey: 'router',
        routerState: RouterState.Minimal
    }),
    StoreModule.forRoot({}, {}),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({ maxAge: 25, logOnly: environment.production })
```

Here is the resolver. The "Here" log is not outputted.

```
/*
    This is the resolver for the mak version models. The function that it
    calls pulls down all of the versions created by a user.
*/


// Common Angular Items
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Resolve, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';


// RxJS Items
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, first, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';



// The mak version entity service
import { makVersionEntityService } from '../services/entity/makVersion-entity.service';


@Injectable()
export class MakVersionsResolver implements Resolve<boolean> {

    constructor(private makVersionEntityService: makVersionEntityService) {

    }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
            state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {

              console.log('Here');

        return this.makVersionEntityService.loaded$
            .pipe(
                tap(loaded => {
                    if (!loaded) {
                      this.makVersionEntityService.getAll();
                    }
                }),
                filter(loaded => !!loaded),
                first()
            );

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently when I added a component through the CLI it added those components to the main app instead of the feature app. I must have missed this and added the component to the feature app manually. The presence of the second declaration caused some problem that resulted in this error. My guess is that it was trying to resolve the resolvers associated with those components in the main app and obviously didn't have the entities included.